# Rails - Roo "file does not exist" error when using Delayed Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, import-from-excel

I'm using the Roo gem to import Excel files, CSV files, etc.

The code works great a) on my local box with or without Delayed Job, and b) on Heroku without Delayed Job. Unfortunately when running on Heroku it fails if I'm using Delayed Job.

Here are the details.

Controller:

```
def importdo
  fileimport = Fileimport.new
  fileimport.file_name = params[:file].original_filename
  fileimport.file_path = params[:file].path
  fileimport.save
  fileimportid = fileimport.id
  Building.delay.import(fileimportid)
  redirect_to buildings_path, notice: "Buildings import started . . . you will receive an email upon completion."
end
```

`fileimport` is just a table I use to keep track of the filename and filepath (I tried to pass these as params but DelayedJob would always have problems when trying to convert the hash to YAML, so I just pass in the record ID instead). This also gives me the benefit of keeping track of my importing in a table.

Here is my import class method:

```
def self.import(fileimportid)
    fileimport = Fileimport.find(fileimportid)
    file_name = fileimport.file_name
    file_path = fileimport.file_path
    newcount = 0
    updatecount = 0
    updating = false
    Building.acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => false
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file_name, file_path)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]

        if zip = row["zip"].to_i.to_s
            if zip.length > 5
                zip = zip.first(5)
            end
        else
            raise "zip not valid"
        end

        if building = find_by_address_and_zip(row["address"], zip)
            updating = true
        else
            building = Building.new
        end
        #building.name = row["name"]
        building.zip = zip
        building.address = row["address"]
        building.city = row["city"]
        building.save!
        if updating
            updatecount += 1
        else
            newcount += 1
        end
        updating=false
    end
    Building.acts_as_gmappable :process_geocoding => true

    subject = "Your Building Import Completed Successfully!"
    body = "Your Building Import completed successfully!\n\n" + newcount.to_s + " buildings were created.\n" + updatecount.to_s + " buildings were updated."

    require 'rest_client'

    RestClient.post MAILGUN_API_URL+"/messages", :from => "obfuscated", :to => "obfuscated", :subject => subject, :text => body 

end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file_name, file_path)
    case File.extname(file_name)
        when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file_path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file_path, nil, :ignore)
        when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file_path, nil, :ignore)
    else
        raise "Unknown file type: #{file_name}"
    end
end
```

Here is my form for the file input:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Import Buildings') %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                Import Products
            </h1>
            <%= form_tag importdo_buildings_path, multipart: true do %>
                <%= file_field_tag :file %>
                <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
            <% end %>
        </section>
    </aside>
</div>
```

The route looks like this:

```
resources :buildings do
    collection { post :importdo }
end
```

Anyway, like I said, works great on my box (both with and without delayed job). Only works on Heroku without delayed job (i.e. I have to take out .delay). Here is the specific error I'm getting (the errors are emailed to me, I use an observer to check when Delayed::Job saves a record and check for last_error):

```
file /tmp/RackMultipart20130516-13-7li3o7 does not exist
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.11.2/lib/roo/excel.rb:26:in `block in initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.11.2/lib/roo/generic_spreadsheet.rb:579:in `block in make_tmpdir'
/app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tmpdir.rb:83:in `mktmpdir'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.11.2/lib/roo/generic_spreadsheet.rb:578:in `make_tmpdir'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.11.2/lib/roo/excel.rb:19:in `initialize'
/app/app/models/building.rb:84:in `new'
/app/app/models/building.rb:84:in `open_spreadsheet'
/app/app/models/building.rb:39:in `import'
```

My initial thought was that it just a Heroku filesystem thing, but then I would think it wouldn't work without delayed_job either. My other thought is that because it is asynchronous maybe it is a timing issue (maybe the temp file either isn't there yet or isn't there anymore).

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: i haven't used DJ on Heroku, but I have used Resque--and I had to make sure the workers were spun up. Do you have dynos spun up to handle the Delayed Job work?

Comment: I'm using workless, and DelayedJob is running because that is what is giving me the error. I could try turning off workless and just have the worker ready in case it is a timing thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial idea was correct.. It is Heroku file system behind your issue. Namely read only rule!

When you send file to Heroku it is stored in temporary folder and available during this one request only. It works without delayed_job because you do your job during one request and file is available.

But delayed_job is being done separately when request is over and thus file is deleted.

The simplest solution is to place file in some cloud storage (I used S3 and  carrierwave for that purpose.